# How to delete all files (or the entire content of all files) with less than 250 words with Regex?

Tags: python, notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, python3

Is it possible to delete all files (or the entire content of all files) with less than 250 words?

I try this regex, but needs to be improved a little bit. Can anyone help me?

- Find: `(?s)(.*?(\w+\s?){1,250}).*$`
- Replace with: `(EMPTY)`

Comment: We are not a free code writing service but a community of people that are interested in computers and dedicate part of their time do helping others. If you already have something in mind and it just doesn’t work, please post it so that we might help.

Comment: Yes, but we have to help each other, don't we? And I tried an answer, I'm sure I was very close to the optimal solution. 

Of course, this question was asked for those who want to lend a helping hand.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood you. I wrote this comment from the first questions review queue, and it seemed to me that you just copied the expression from somewhere and it didn't work.

Comment: An editor is not the right tool to do such job.The best way is to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: I am very sure, regex can done this. But I'm missing something...

Comment: so you plan to open each of these files interactively and manually run a find/replace? that seems silly, and is what Toto is commenting on. Regex is not the issue here, its the notepad++/sublime that seem wrong. why not write a script that runs your regex and deletes the file, so you could run it on many files at once? isn't that why you have a python tag on the question?

Comment: What is a word for you? Only alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]`, alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, word character `\w`, everything that is not a space or something else?

Comment: Only alphabetic [a-zA-Z]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in comment, you considere a word only composed with letters, this will work for you:

- Find what: `\A(?i)[^a-z]*(?:[a-z]+[^a-z]+){0,249}(?:[a-z]+[^a-z]*)?\z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

**Explanation:**

```
\A          # beginning of file
(?i)        # case insensitive
    [^a-z]*     # 0 or more non letter
    (?:         # non capture group
        [a-z]+      # 1 or more letter
        [^a-z]+     # 1 or more non letter
    ){0,249}    # end group, may appear 0 up to 249 times
    (?:         # non capture group
        [a-z]+      # 1 or more letter
        [^a-z]*     # 0 or more non letter
    )?          # end group, optional
\z          # end of file
```

Comment: brilliant. Thank you !

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case to delete content of files **with less than 250 words** , see the [SOURCE](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/22815/delete-the-entire-content-of-all-files-with-less-than-100-words/13?_=1649309315151)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `(?s)\A[[:space:]]*(?:[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){0,251}[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*\z|\A[[:space:]]+\z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**The second case:**

Use the following for the second case, to delete content of files **with more than 250 words**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `(?s)(.*?(\w+\s+){249,}).*\Z` **OR** `(?s)\A(.*?(\w+\s+){249}).*\Z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/9umTEv/1) I'm using your regex to match file with less than 2 words. It matches a file with 9 words! In fact that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I made this Python code, to delete all Files With Less Than 250 Characters. Maybe someone needs it. See both variants of code [HERE:](https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-delete-all-files-with-less-than-250-characters.html)

```
import os
import re
import random
import unidecode
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
# nltk.download('punkt')
import requests
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage
 
def read_text_from_file(file_path):
    """
    Aceasta functie returneaza continutul unui fisier.
    file_path: calea catre fisierul din care vrei sa citesti
    """
    with open(file_path, encoding='utf8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
        return text
 
FOLDER_LOCAL = 'd:\\Folder1'
 
counter_sterse = 0
for f in os.listdir(FOLDER_LOCAL):
    if f.endswith('.html') or f.endswith('.htm'):
        filepath = os.path.join(FOLDER_LOCAL, f)
        page_html = read_text_from_file(filepath)
        if len(page_html) < 250:
            os.remove(filepath)
            counter_sterse += 1
            continue
 
print("S-au sters {} fisiere".format(counter_sterse))
```

Comment: This is counting the number of characters, not the number of words.

Comment: yes, I can make another code to delete words, but it is almost the same...

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to be opening each file in Notepad++ interactively anyway, there is already a feature for counting words. just double-click in the bottom bar where it says "Length", to view the document summary with word count.

[image: Notepad++ document summary]

you can see more about this method, and even a regex for it here:
[https://appuals.com/check-the-word-count-in-notepad/#:~:text=Open%20your%20Notepad%2B%2B%20by,word%20count%20of%20the%20document](https://appuals.com/check-the-word-count-in-notepad/#:%7E:text=Open%20your%20Notepad%2B%2B%20by,word%20count%20of%20the%20document).